# How to measure network transfer speed against a host from the command line?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

I want to measure bandwidth against a host from the command line.

Many hosts will be on the internet and outside my control. This will serve to test my actual internet connection bandwidth. I am aware that the connection to a site may be slower than my total bandwidth, depending on how things are set up server side. I am planning to control for this myself, by running the speedtest against several reliable hosts.

Solutions like SCP will not work because I don't have SSH access to google.com.

I will also be using this for hosts on my LAN, which I control. So an ideal solution would be downloading resources from a webpage, and I can run nginx with a dummy website just for the sake of making it compatible with the test method.

My goal is to diagnose my internet connection. I want to compare the bandwidth of my connection to the internet vs. to just my router, and I want to do this many times over time so I can see if there's times of day when it is slow. I know other programs that happen to be running while the speedtest is going may happen to distort results, but I'm willing to deal with that when analyzing the data.

Previously, I used the [Speedtest CLI](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli) but this is very limited. It only uses that company's servers, takes a very long time, and I can't use it to test the LAN bandwidth.

Answer (score -1):

> Many hosts will be on the internet and outside my control.

You basically can't. The other host has to cooperate with you; it can cooperate in the sense that it sends data in response to a HTTP request you make (i.e., when you download a file). But then you would need to trust it to do that as quickly as its connection allows. And usually, larger HTTP servers don't do that – they have traffic shaping (because at some volume, you need to take into account that you pay for the bandwidth of your connection, and you're better off making sure that the people with small requests are served and gone than that the guy with the 2 GB request is 25% faster).

Other hosts will simply not offer HTTP or any other service that's useful for or simply not offer large files. Small files are not an option; the request and acknowledgement overhead is important.

> I used the Speedtest CLI but this is very limited. It only uses that company's servers, takes a very long time

Well, I don't know how the commercial structure behind all this is, but these servers simply have someone who's willing to pay for the traffic necessary to make a reliable test. And note that this inherently means that the test can't be over in a fraction of a second – there's not only the connection time overhead, but there's also active traffic shaping on ISPs' sides.

So, it seems to me you want something impossible.

Luckily, I think you also want something useless – if you want a application-level  reliability and throughput measure, then *measure the application, not something else*. In other words, if you want to know how fast youtube is, then use `yt-dlp` (or another youtube client) to download the rickroll video. If you want to test how well your SSH connection works, then do an SSH test. If you want to test how well your IMAP server connection works, then get a listing of an mail folder with 20000 mails in it and time it, then make a new folder, put a 20 MB mail into, delete it and the folder again and time that. If you want to know how performant DNS resolution is, then ask your DNS resolver to resolve.
Will this lead to numbers that you can directly compare across different servers offering different services? No.
Will the numbers actually mean something to your usage? Yes!

> I will also be using this for hosts on my LAN, which I control.

If you want to test your  LAN bandwidth: uh, that's just a function of your network card(s) and your switch(es). Unless you're involving NIC speeds beyond 25 Gb/s (which I'm almost sure you would have mentioned), a modern PC can and will saturate the wire speed in a LAN, if using maximum packet sizes and avoiding overly regularly acknowledging receipt of package.

If you want to test the ability of your computers to react to specific application requests (say, SMB/CIFS file sharing, video streaming, backup receiving), then, again, test these actual applications.

For the case that you're actually intending on stress-testing your *network stack* (and not the application-level software/operating system/hardware cooperation), then `iperf3` might be the command-line application of your choice. But, again, a modern PC will just saturate 1 Gb/s ethernet without as much as blinking an eye, unless you configure things intentionally to be inefficient (small packets, short contention windows, artificial packet drop).